# find numbers and chars on an image

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm tring to bulid a program that should recognized the serial number
on **containers**.
there will me a camera and the input of the camera will be an image of truck
with a containers on it and the output will be the truck number and the container number.
I'm not sure if I should use open cv or machine learning for that and what is better. 
Not like the truck license plate, the container number is not allways write in the same way and some times there are more numbers,but it's allways 4 letters and then 7 numbers so I need some function (opencv or machine learning/knn) that recognize any letter and number on the container.

I added some images to show how it's look.
Thank's
Amit

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a thing you want to solve using an OCR (or Optical Character Recognition). This kind of software allows you to feed it images or documents and tries to recognize characters anywhere.

I've had some great results using [Google Tesseract](https://opensource.google.com/projects/tesseract).

If you want to control Tesseract using Python (albeit in a limited way) there is always the option to install [PyTesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20149260)

Comment: @IanS: Sorry but I do think it's an answer to the underlying question. OP clearly states he is still in the fase of ***trying*** to build an OCR (basically). Linking to things like Tesseract might not solve the problem of needing an opencv or knn solution but imho does help with the problem underneath.

Comment: You're right, but the question is off-topic for SO. If you had the reputation this would be a great comment. Still upvoting you :)